# Styling the Share Action Provider in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-theme, shareactionprovider

[image]

Here is how I share the content through Share Action Provider:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "Check the Link  : " + url);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share with"));
```

I want to style the share with window. I want to change the text color and highlighter line color from default blue color to my custom color. I am using Holo light theme. I don't know how to style those elements. Can anyone point out a reference to do that?

Is there a way to access attributes of android.widget.ShareActionProvider through styling?

Comment: Can you be a bit clear on what you want exactly? It would be better if you could show your previous code and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot style the chooser dialog. It is a system-level actvity, and uses the default system theme.

Comment: okay. Where can I find the style elements for android.widget.ShareActionProvider? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to style the dialog, i have seen different layouts in different devices. But you can use `PackageManager.queryIntentActivities(Intent intent, int flag)` to get all activities that could handle this intent. And use the list data to create your own chooser.

EDIT: a demo

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> infos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    CharSequence[] names = new CharSequence[infos.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < infos.size(); i++) {
        names[i] = infos.get(i).loadLabel(pm);
    }
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setItems(names,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ResolveInfo info = infos.get(which);
                    intent.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName,
                            info.activityInfo.name);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }).show();
```

Comment: I cannot find a reference, so i write a demo for you.

Comment: Thanks @faylon. Good piece of work. I made some design changes to make that available to my application theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like this

```
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,getString(R.string.app_name));
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,getString(R.string.tell_your_frnd));
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> infos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        name = new String[infos.size()];
        image=new Drawable[infos.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < infos.size(); i++) 
        {
            name[i] = (String) infos.get(i).loadLabel(pm);
            image[i]=infos.get(i).loadIcon(pm);
        }


        CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(ShareActivity.this,name,image);
        mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
        {

            ResolveInfo info = infos.get(position);

            intent.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName,
                    info.activityInfo.name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```